# Cancel async task?

Tags: c#, async-await

My code isn't canceling the tasks correctly and I'm still seeing my series in my graph being drawn for the next series in the `foreach` loop... not sure what I'm doing wrong here as I want to exit and cancel all async tasks at this point... any ideas?

```
    private void StartTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        if (_isRunning)
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }

        _isRunning = !_isRunning;
        Start(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    private async void Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        foreach (var buttonSelected in selectedButtons)
        {
            // If cancellation requested
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;

            // Retrieve series to reflect changes on
            var seriesToChange = Model.Series.Where(x => x.Title == buttonSelected.Name).ToArray();

            // Create timer
            var timerForPlotting = new DispatcherTimer();
            if (seriesToChange .Length == 1)
            {
                // Set the series to visible
                seriesToChange [0].IsVisible = true;

                timerForPlotting.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
                timerForPlotting.Tick += (object s, EventArgs a) => PlotSeriesPoints_Tick(s, a, seriesToChange [0]);
            }

            // Start
            InitiateTimerWithButtonUIChange(timerForPlotting, buttonSelected, false);

            // Set the task to only take a couple of seconds
            await Task.Delay(2000);

            // End
            InitiateTimerWithButtonUIChange(timerForPlotting, buttonSelected, true);
        }
    }

    private void InitiateTimerWithButtonUIChange(DispatcherTimer timer, Button buttonSelected, bool isFinished)
    {
        if (!isFinished)
        {
            timer.Start();
            buttonSelected.Background = resourceDictionary["Processing"] as Brush;
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
            buttonSelected.Background = resourceDictionary["ColourActive"] as Brush;

            // Reset
            time = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The logic in the `StartTest_Click` method seems completely whacky.

Comment: You are always re-creating the CancellationTokenSource so the one used in the running task is not the one you are canceling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call `Cancel()` on the actual `CancellationTokenSource` that you used to create the token that you passed to `Start`:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
private void StartTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cancellationTokenSource != null)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
    }

    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _isRunning = !_isRunning;
    Start(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you also have to assign `null` to `cancellationTokenSource` in the if statement?

Comment: @ColinM why assign null? Will be assign a new value on cancellationTokenSource after

Comment: Never mind, ignore me - there is no return statement so the code will continue to where it's assigned. My apologies..

Comment: Copy and pasted this... doesn't seem to work though :( still continues to produce tasks....

Comment: "Produce tasks"? Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm probably missing some logic to say if the button is pressed again, don't do start integration or the initialisation of the cancellationtokensource because it'll go in an endless loop of cancelling and recreating itself

Comment: Thing is i'm using the same button to start and stop the test, so the name of my event handler for the click function is a bit misleading.... i'm using this button as a start and stop... so obviously when you press it for the second time, you want things to cancel and stop... but it won't because there's no checks for that..

Comment: My example does stop but then it immediately calls Start again. So you are cancelling *and* starting a new task on each click.

Comment: aha... yes my question probably lacked detail... i'm using the button to start, and if you click it again it will stop... that's what i was looking for

Comment: Well, please ask a new question if you have another issue.